# How to add an AddType to an apache server

Tags: php, apache

I am currently working with the Uniform Server and I would like to learn how to apply an AddType to it, so that my custom fonts, (i.e. a .otf font), is registered when I use that font on my PHP pages.  This is the message I get via my console log via Google Chrome, when I am using my custom font...

> Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type
>   application/x-font-otf: htt://.../mfont.otf

I did some digging, and so far came up with the following line that needs to be integrated...

```
AddType application/x-font-otf
```

But I'm clueless on where to put, or how to fix issues like this.  But I want to learn!

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Depends on how it was installed, what operating system/package/etc (some pull from multiple config files, some use 1 big file). It needs to go in httpd.conf. or in a file included from httpd.conf What OS are you using, that might help pinpoint the exact location.

Comment: I am using windows vista.  I installed it as one .exe package.  Every time I bring up the uniform server pop-up window, it says "Server - Program - 8.6.7" up at top.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert

```
AddType application/x-font-otf
```

in

If you are using xampp
C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/apace/conf/httpd.conf

Still Not working

```
 AddType  font/opentype
```

Comment: I'm not using xampp, but thank you for the general location and confirmation on how to write it. I found that file in the uniform server.  thank you!

Comment: sucks, I'm still getting that message, after reloading my apache server.

Comment: do restart your serives before testing anything. If you are still getting error. post it here.

Comment: It's what I posted above... - Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/x-font-otf: htt://.../mfont.otf

Comment: the server is not generating no errors, but Google chrome keeps posting the "resource" warning message...and I don't know how to remove that...

Comment: I tried adding AddType font/otf .otf, directly onto the .htaccess file, and Chrome, still shows the warning message...

Comment: use this  "font/opentype".

Comment: I came across this problem before, so I looked what I did in my httpd.conf.

Comment: Thanks again, that was a big help!

Answer (score 1):

Look for a file named "httpd.conf" and put it inside that file. I have no experience on Uniform Server but since it's running Apache, putting the line inside the apache httpd.conf file should work.

Comment: thanks, and found the location, but after saving and reloading apache, I still get that warning message in my browser.